# keras model , value to c++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras

i'm developing a little python program with python3.6, keras1.X and Opencv4 on win10, however i would like to run it or make it return recognition result of digits to C++ because of my project request.

I've tried convert to .pb model and however tensorflow's support to c++ is so weird, i need to concern about cuda cudnn, python, keras2, opencv version and even compile the tensorflow would be such a trouble on win10.

So i'm wandering is there any other way for predicting single digit and return value for C++ engineers? I've searched about popen and pyinitialize, the second one failed beacuse of the encoding problem, c++ couldn't find the pythonhome even i set it, i'm still working on the front one but not sure will it work.

Please note and remind me what am i missing, any way would help currently, appreciate!!

Comment: I think you better use onnx. You can convert your model into onnx and use it in c++.

Comment: Hi! I have just tried to convert my model into onnx and ran it in tensorflow successfully!TAT. However it couldn't run properly with opencv's dnn module, i was kind of resize and reshap jpg file with imread function and  it returns error like this:blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(digit_image),   image0.dims == 2 in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20210301::blobFromImages'